# Comparing two variables of type "object"

Tags: c#, object, comparison, unity-game-engine, system.reflection

I have a rather complex question that I'm struggling to find a workaround to.

Basically, because the Unity engine does not support .NET 4, I'm struggling to find a an alternative to using variables of type "dynamic".

Some background: I am creating a game that has a lot of unlockable content. Our goal is to have a big dictionary that contains all the conditions and their associated rewards (all hard-coded by us for now). Then, whenever the player does something that could result in an unlock, we want to check certain entries in the dictionary to see if they should be unlocked. We want it this way so we would only have to write a small loop to check to see if the player has unlocked anything, as opposed to having to pepper literally hundreds of if statements all over our code.

Problem is, the particular fields that need to be checked could be in any of our scripts. For example, the game may need to check if the player owns a certain amount of an item (in our Inventory script) or if they have played a certain level (in our Level dictionary). Reflection seemed to solve our problem, but now comparison operators are causing a headache.

For reference, here's my "Condition" class, used to store what fields need to be compared to each other in order to unlock a specific reward:

```
public class Condition
{
    public enum condOper { Greater, Lesser, Equals, NotEquals, GreaterOrEquals, LesserOrEquals};
    public Type Script1;
    public Type Script2;
    public string Property1;
    public string Property2;
    public string Key1;
    public string Key2;
    public condOper condOperator;
}
```

The script variables are which scripts the fields are in, the property variables are which properties can be used to access the fields, the key variables are used whenever we need to check a specific entry in a dictionary, and the last variable is what comparison operator to use between the two fields.

So here's my code I'm trying to use to compare the two fields in a Condition:

```
    //Create two variables for the fields
    object property1 = condition.Script1.GetField(condition.Property1).GetValue(null);
    object property2 = condition.Script2.GetField(condition.Property2).GetValue(null);

    //Do a different conditional check based on the operator
    bool result;
    if (condition.condOperator == Condition.condOper.Greater)
        result = property1 > property2;
    else if(condition.condOperator == Condition.condOper.Lesser)
        result = property1 < property2;
    ...
```

Note that all of the fields we're looking for are static, hence the "null" in the GetValue.

The error I am getting is that the operator (< or >) can't be used between two "objects".

Declaring them as type "dynamic" and having some try-catches would work, but unfortunately Unity doesn't support .NET 4. Statically typing the "property1" and "property2" variables won't work since there has to be support for multiple types since not all of our fields will be ints, floats, etc.

So, TLDR, is there a way I can use comparison operators like ">" or "==" between two variables of type "object"?

Comment: You could override the GetHashCode method to make it fit your requirements, and use that, since all objects has that method.
That way, you have the equality operator (==)

Comment: If you know that the object represents a number or a string, you could try casting or parsing it to an integer

Comment: Using reflection looks like a code smell for me. You should implement some smarter abstraction. Maybe try to cast these properties to IComparable?

Comment: @apocalypse Are you suggesting to try to cast the properties after I retrieve them with reflection or that casting them would somehow eliminate the need for it? I haven't dug deep into that interface so I'm curious if could eliminate the need for all the variables to find something using reflection.

Comment: @MalteR If I knew all the potential values would be floats, strings, or ints, I would attempt a parse on the object, but as of now I don't know which properties we might have to check, so I have to assume it could be any type. As far as overriding GetHashCode, you're thinking maybe just override it to take the second object as a parameter, compare them, then return a bool? I need a solution that can do any comparison, not just ==, so will this work?

Comment: Using GetHashCode() will only make the == operator meaningful, but IComparable, as apocalypse suggests, will help you achieve all sorts of comparisons (<, >, >=, ...)

Comment: @GReusch: after you receive two objects using reflection, you can *try* to cast them to `IComparable` and use `CompareTo` method to compare them. Of course there is no guarantee these objects will implement this interface. But it will work for many built-in types, like string, int, float etc. You will not find magic method which will compare everything in the world. If you create a new class `Fruit`, you need to implement code that will compare it with another fruit instance. I suggest you to build a better abstraction (without reflection).

Comment: @apocalypse As it stands, I'm not under the impression that we will be comparing anything that isn't a basic (or at least built-in) type. I don't foresee us making any custom classes that need compared, so I will try implementing this later today and let you know if it worked. What suggestions would you have for not using reflection, however? I don't see any way to go about it since all of the values are in different scripts. Thanks for the help so far